# how can make Custom Delegate For Custom UIView objective c , OK button not working

Tags: objective-c

Here is my affected code:

```
#import "AddTeamView.h"
#import <AFNetworking.h>

@implementation AddTeamView

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{

    self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

    self=[super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        [self customInit];

    }
    return self;
}
-(void)customInit
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"AddTeamView" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:self.contentView];
}
- (IBAction)okButton:(UIButton *)sender
{

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"team_name":self.enterNameTextField.text

                            };
    [manager POST:@"https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/times?q=team_name" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        }progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

//        [self stopHud];
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        NSDictionary *response = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSInteger statusCode = error.code;
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)statusCode);

      //  [self stopHud];


    }];




}
```

I create a `.Xib` file like:

[image]

When I press on `Ok` button, the response doesn't come and nothing happens.
Now how can I declare custom `Delegate` for custom `UIView`
and why delegate is required here? Can anyone kindly explain what can I do to get the response of API?

Comment: Have you created a delegate there in your custom view? If yes then add this line in your code. AddTeamView.delegate = self;

Comment: No , not creating , how can create delegate ?

Comment: Ok let me add some steps

Comment: Are you able to do this delegate issue? or still working on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your AddTeamView.h and this code.

```
@protocol AddTeamDelegate <NSObject>

  - (IBAction)okButton:(UIButton *)sender;

@end

@property id <AddTeamDelegate> delegate;
```

And synthesize this property in AddTeamView.m file as below.

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

Add this code In your viewController.h file where you are adding AddTeamView as subview.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AddTeamDelegate>
```

In your viewController.m file add this code while adding AddTeamView as subView.

```
AddTeamView.delegate = self;
```

and add this method for Ok button in same file

```
- (IBAction)okButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"team_name":self.enterNameTextField.text

                        };
[manager POST:@"https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/times?q=team_name" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    }progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

//        [self stopHud];
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    NSDictionary *response = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSInteger statusCode = error.code;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)statusCode);

  //  [self stopHud];
}];
}
```

Comment: in which file , i can add OK button ?

Comment: In your viewController.m where you are adding AddTeamView as a subview.

Comment: Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'AddTeamView'

Comment: IqraUmar add this line @synthesize delegate; in your AddTeamView.m file

Comment: i did it , thank you for your positive and quick response